# Tests needed for repeated measures within groups 2*2 design?

Tags: anova

I've recently conducted an experiment with two independent variables: musictype and wordtype, measured by response time. 20 participants. I've done a one-way repeated measures ANOVA along with the usual tests of normality, means etc. Do I need to include a t-test? Am I missing any other important tests?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a resource you might want to look at. It is provided by a vendor - NCSS - that I don't use. That said, was looking at their products on the weekend. Even though you likely don't use their software, you can get a good idea of how to analyze a repeated measures 2 x 2 design & how to review the tests. The document is called: [Tests for Two Means in a Repeated Measures Design](http://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tests_for_Two_Means_in_a_Repeated_Measures_Design.pdf).

As they note in the summary, to clarify the definition for unfamiliar users: "A repeated measures design is one in which subjects are observed repeatedly over time. Measurements may be taken at pre-determined intervals (e.g. weekly or at specified time points following the administration of a particular treatment), or at random times so there are variable intervals between repeated measurements."

If you are looking for tactical guidance, and happen to use R, you might want [to have a look at this excellent R tutorial](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/repeated.html). In this tutorial, you will see a few relevant tests completed, including:

- **The Friedman Rank Sum Test**
- **Pairwise t-tests with adjusted p-values**

Comment: I'm using SPSS, the first link is very helpful though, thank you!